# Getting polish characters in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

using the below code I extracted the table and made it into a csv file

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_html('https://www.ebmia.pl/lozyska-kulkowe-zwykle-seria-c-196_140_1328_1282_3375.html')[0]
x.to_csv('file.csv')
```

While doing this all the polish characters like "Ł" is converted into "?" in csv file.

How can I get the original polish characters in csv file.

Comment: does this work: `pd.read_html('https://www.ebmia.pl/lozyska-kulkowe-zwykle-seria-c-196_140_1328_1282_3375.html', encoding='utf-8')`, it seems to preserve the polish characters for me

Comment: Maybe need parameter `encoding='utf-8'`. Hard to answer without your file. Is possible upload 10 rows file to dropbox, gdocs?

Comment: `x` is a list. How is this code running? It isn't valid.

Comment: i took 1st element from list x. I missed that in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need paramter `encoding='utf-8'`, for return first parsed table add `[0]`, because [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) return list of `DataFrames`:

```
url = 'https://www.ebmia.pl/lozyska-kulkowe-zwykle-seria-c-196_140_1328_1282_3375.html'
df = pd.read_html(url, encoding='utf-8')[0]
```

Some data cleaning:

```
#remove first level in columns with filters in html
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)
#replace NaN by forward filling
df['Zdjęcie'] = df['Zdjęcie'].ffill()
#remove NaNs rows by checking Wewnętrzny mm  column
df = df.dropna(subset=['Wewnętrzny mm '])
print (df.head())
                                              Zdjęcie Oznaczenie  ⇓  \
4   Łożysko kulkowe zwykłe 16001 NSK - (symbol: L0...         16001   
7   Łożysko kulkowe zwykłe 16001 ZZ FAG - (symbol:...      16001 2Z   
10  Łożysko kulkowe zwykłe 16002.SKF - (symbol: L0...         16002   
13  Łożysko kulkowe zwykłe 16002-A.FAG - (symbol: ...         16002   
16  Łożysko kulkowe zwykłe 16002 - (symbol: L0101-...         16002   

    Wewnętrzny mm   Zewnętrzny mm   Szerokość / wysokość mm  Zabudowa  Luz   \
4           1200.0          2800.0                     700.0         -    -   
7           1200.0          2800.0                     700.0        2Z    -   
10          1500.0          3200.0                     800.0         -    -   
13          1500.0          3200.0                     800.0         -    -   
16          1500.0          3200.0                     800.0         -    -   

                   Producent Cena(brutto)  
4   NSK BEARINGS POLSKA S.A.     22,14 zł  
7                        NaN          NaN  
10                       NaN     31,34 zł  
13                       NaN     17,11 zł  
16                       NaN      5,40 zł
```

If need write output to `csv`:

```
df.to_csv('file', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Same parameter working for [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```